# Standard Object Permissions

Tags: sharing, relationships

If a standard object has only read access, then does it mean it a user can access all child object records related to standard object?

Example: If I give read access to order object for a user, then will he able to access or read  order products related information ? 
Or I need to give view all object permission for Order object?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the relationships and the Organization Wide Defaults (OWD):

*Sharing rule play into this as well and grant additional access*

**Lookup**

The record access is controlled by the OWD. If the user does not have access to the related object they will see no records. Likewise, if they have Public Read on the related object, they can see all of the records regardless of the OWD of the parent

*Example 1*

- Account has a lookup to Custom__c
- Account is set to Private
- Custom__c is set to Public Read

> - The user will only see Accounts that they own or have been granted
>     access to.
> - The user will see ALL Custom__c regardless of their
>     relationship to the Account record

*Example 2*

- Account has a lookup to Custom__c
- Account is set to Public Read
- Custom__c is set to Private

> - The user will see All Accounts
> - The user will only see Custom__c records they own or have been granted access to

**Master Detail**

The access to the related records is based off of the OWD settings of the parent. Access to these records is controlled by the parent OWD settings

*Example*

- Custom__c is a detail of Account
- Account is Private

> The user will only see Custom__c records related to Account that they
>   own or have been granted access to

**Note** Via API, records that are a detail in a Master-Detail of another object, the OwnerId field is not available. This again is a clue that the sharing/security is based on the parent

[Help and Training - Object Relationship Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=overview_of_custom_object_relationships.htm&type=0)